# Random Wordpress posts outside of the main loop without duplicate posts. How?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, random

Well I can't figure this one out...

I have this Wordpress I use as a photo gallery blog.

I have a basic setup using the main default loop for posts.

Like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

//the post

<?php endwhile; ?>

<b>Not Found</b>

<?php endif; ?>
```

In the sidebar and where ever, I want to appear random posts.

I've managed to do that. With this:

```
<?php query_posts($query_string . 'showposts=1&orderby=rand'); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

//the post

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

It looks amazing! In theory.

There are duplicate posts all over the place. And that just looks stupid.

I have read lots of articles but I just can't seem to get it to work :(

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try posting this to [WORDPRESS.STACKEXCHANGE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good night of sleep, here's what I have done:

Creating array with post ID:

```
<?php $already_posted = array(); ?>
```

The Main loop where at the end I record the post ID to array:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

//the post

<?php $already_posted[]= $post->ID; endwhile; ?>

    <?php else : ?>

    <b>Not Found</b>

<?php endif; ?>
```

And the random post code using post__not_in to avoid duplicates and again recording post ID:

```
<?php $args = array( 'numberposts' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand', 'post__not_in' => $already_posted );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>

//the post

<?php $already_posted[]= $post->ID; endforeach; ?>
```

Works evertime!

You can do amazing stuff with this :)

Thanks to paislee and Arvind Pal for helping out.

Comment: This is not working for me. Would there be a problem if my main loop is on index.htm and the random loop is on sidebar.php. I've added my array on sidebar.php, should it be on index.php before the main loop instead?

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this code for random post.
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) : ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

Or You can get help from this url mention below
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts
```

Answer (score 0):

Skip would-be duplicates by remembering displayed ID's from the first loop

```
$displayed = array(); // create an array that we'll use associatively
```

In your first loop, each time:

```
$displayed[get_the_ID()] = TRUE; // <-- save all post IDs in here
```

Change your random loop opening like this:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    // skip  post IDs you've already seen
    if ($displayed[get_the_ID()]) continue;
?>
```

Due to randomness in the number of duplicates, you may want to alter your query so that it gets *all* posts, and change the second loop to `break` once the desired number of random posts is reached.

**Notes**

- `showposts` is depracated. Replace `showposts=1` with `posts_per_page=-1`

Comment: Thank you very much! Only one thing, sometimes it leaves a random post blank. Perhaps that 'break' thing you mentioned has something to do with it... Could you give me some pointers?

Comment: @Christian147 edit your question to include the value of `$query_string` and I'll try to help

Comment: @Christian147 most likely the blank posts are because the `continue` check is not first thing inside the second loop. see my update

Comment: I don't think that $query_string has any value, I removed it and everything still works. Please don't ask me how or why, I've been all over the internet today before coming here :)

Comment: paislee, no more duplicates, thats for sure but still sometimes blank posts. Got some more ideas?

Comment: @Christian147  See my note in the update. And make sure you use the code I just posted for the beginning of the second loop