# How to Show random post on WordPress, except the last published post

Tags: php, wordpress, post, random

I have a website where people can upload articles, but I would like to show a random post, except the last published post on the main page, because if all the post are random, the user can not see his post when recently uploaded.

I was able to locate this, this is the one that I'm currently using

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
function my_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('orderby', 'rand');
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319330/random-wordpress-posts-outside-of-the-main-loop-without-duplicate-posts-how?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Show random post on WP, except the last post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618961/how-to-show-random-post-on-wp-except-the-last-post)

Comment: I only see now that you have posted this twice and already accepted an answer on the other question. You should **not** do that, it might get you blocked for posting duplicates. If an answer does not solve your issue, don't accept that answer and ask the same question again. You **should**ask the answerer for more info, and if you need to add something, file an edit to your original question to clarify some things. **Only** accept answers that actually solve your issue completely and to avoid something like this again. Thank you :-)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i didnt knew that, sorry for the inconvinience

Answer (score 0):

This is totally untested, but you can use `get_posts` to gt the latest post ID and then exclude it from the main query

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
function my_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $newest = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $newest );
        $query->set('orderby', 'rand');
    }
}
```

Comment: Random is what you want according to your question.